# LINQ WHERE method alters source collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a method that returns a new list (it pertains to a multiple choice answer):

```
public static List<questionAnswer> GetAnswersWithSelections(this Questions_for_Exam__c question)
        {
            List<questionAnswer> answers = new List<questionAnswer>();

            answers.Add(new questionAnswer() { Ordinal = 1, AnswerText = question.AN1__c, Selected = (bool)question.Option1__c });

            ...

            return answers;
        }
```

If I examine the result of this method - I see the correct data, e.g. *Red = False, Green = True, Blue = False*

I then try to filter the returned result using the LINQ Where extension method:

```
List<questionAnswer> CorrectSelections = question.GetAnswersWithSelections();

var tmpA = CorrectSelections.Where(opt => opt.Selected = true);
```

When I materialise tmpA, 2 things happen:

1. The data in the SOURCE list changes - E.g. *Red = True, Green =
   True, Blue = True*
2. The data in tmpA is set to the same wrong data
   that the source list has been changed to

Any ideas?

Comment: Hangs head in shame... starts filling in MacDonalds staff application form

Comment: As an aside, your buggy code doesn't alter the source collection; it's actually altering the items stored in the collection.  This is a subtle but important difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `==` and not `=`:

```
var tmpA = CorrectSelections.Where(opt => opt.Selected == true);
```

So when you search for condition, you were setting values.
This is a common mistake, I fall for it as well :)

Answer (score 7):

your line

```
opt => opt.Selected = true
```

needs another equals sign:

```
opt => opt.Selected == true
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `opt.Selected == true`. You have a single `=`

Answer (score 0):

change  `=` to  `==` in your linq code.